# What does "run the place" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

"Virginia's state government seemed unable to find anyone to run the place who has not either applied boot polish to his face while at college or been accused of sexual assault. "
What do "run the place" and "either applied boot polish to his face while at college or been accused of sexual assault" mean in the sentence?

Comment: "Run the place" means "manage the business or other organisation". "Applying boot polish to the face" refers to the practice of [blackface (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackface).

Comment: @n.m. Put a couple of citations in that and you have a complete answer - go for it.

Comment: 'Run the place' is to be in charge of it. 'To have the run of the place' simply means to have free access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Run the place" in this context means "Lead the government of the state of Virginia."

All of the available leaders have been accused of unacceptable past behavior: "applying boot polish" means applying something black to the face to mimic African complexion. "accused of sexual assault" is a legal term; assault can mean many things, including touching, inappropriate comments, threats, and demands.